# Extracting portion of a proc/status linux file

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string, fedora

First, I'm totally beginner in linux and C language, I can't relate C to c++ or java much when it comes to strings!. I'm using Fedora16 - linux - and I want to read a proc/[pid]/status file to get specific information from it, such as PPID and state, then I should print these info on the screen - command line terminal-. This must be done by writing a c script in gedit. My only issue is that I'm new to c, and dealing with strings in c seems very frustrating to me! I have already opened the file and view it on my terminal by executing the c file. Is there any possible way to store the whole content in one string variable and then I can tokenize it and store the chunks of data as in string array not char array, then I know where my wanted data is in the array and I can access it?

Here is my code though

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{


const char line[200];
const char junk[200];

FILE *file = fopen("/proc/14/status", "r");

// while not end of the file
while(!feof(file)) {

fscanf(file,"%s",line); //Get text into line array

printf("%s\n", line);

//fscanf(file,"%[ \n\t\r]s",junk); //Remove any 'white space' characters

               }//end while

fclose(file);

}
```

**Output On Terminal:**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: For a general idea about how to write this kind of code, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724946/change-niceness-of-all-processes-by-niceness/32726172#32726172)

Comment: For strings in C, it's actually extremely simple: they do not exist. C only knows *string literals* that translate to an array of `char` with a `0` at the end and just evaluate to a pointer to their first `char`. So, think pointers and arrays, not strings. BTW, the term *c-string* sometimes used means exactly that: an array of `char` with zero at the end. `string.h` has a lot of functions for basic operations on that kind of "strings", just look at an overview.

Comment: And as a last remark: **never** use a plain `%s` in `scanf()`, it will eventually overflow any buffer and is a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong initially

1. `line` should not be `const`.
2. `while (!feof(file))` is almost always wrong.

The fix involves doing something like

```
while (fscanf(file, "%199s", line) == 1)
```

which will loop until there is no more data and will prevent overflowing `line`.

This will fix something, the other thing is rather complicated, first try using `fgets()` instead if `fscanf()`, it will consume lines from the file including the `'\n'` and the embedded white spaces

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
```

then you can try `sscanf()` checking it's return value to ensure that it succeeded.

From the content of `/proc/self/status` you can see that `strchr()` would do a good job in splitting the lines in the interesting parts.

This is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    char line[100];
    file = fopen("/proc/self/status", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1; /* Failure to open /proc/self/stat -- very unlikely */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
    {
        char *tail;
        char *key;
        char *value;
        tail = strchr(line, '\n');
        if (tail != NULL)
            *tail = '\0'; /* remove the trailing '\n' */
        tail = strchr(line, ':');
        if (tail != NULL)
        {
            tail[0] = '\0';
            key = strdup(line);
            if (key == NULL)
                continue;
            tail += 1;
            while ((tail[0] != '\0') && (isspace((int) tail[0]) != 0))
                tail++;
            value = strdup(tail);
            if (value != NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s --> %s\n", key, value);
                /* You could do something now with key/value */
                free(value);
            }
            free(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That last line when every key and value are saved in a char variable helped me a lot! now I can print the specific info that I want, thank you.